# How to animate a SVG with CSS inside <style> tag

Tags: css, svg

I would like to animate a SVG logo with CSS code like I did in this website:

https://svgartista.net/

It splits the svg code and the transition code like that:

```css
svg .svg-elem-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 672.049560546875px;
  stroke-dasharray: 672.049560546875px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.8s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.8s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(0, 204, 174);
}

svg .svg-elem-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 248.2175750732422px;
  stroke-dasharray: 248.2175750732422px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.12s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.9s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.12s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.9s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-3 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 217.32936096191406px;
  stroke-dasharray: 217.32936096191406px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.24s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.24s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-3 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-4 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 258.3160705566406px;
  stroke-dasharray: 258.3160705566406px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.36s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.1s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.36s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.1s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-4 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-5 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 255.83644104003906px;
  stroke-dasharray: 255.83644104003906px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.48s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.2000000000000002s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.48s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.2000000000000002s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-5 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-6 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 287.2906494140625px;
  stroke-dasharray: 287.2906494140625px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.6s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.3s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.6s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.3s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-6 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-7 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 179.39129638671875px;
  stroke-dasharray: 179.39129638671875px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.72s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.4000000000000001s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.72s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.4000000000000001s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-7 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-8 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 113.3043212890625px;
  stroke-dasharray: 113.3043212890625px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.84s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.5s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.84s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.5s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-8 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-9 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 248.21778869628906px;
  stroke-dasharray: 248.21778869628906px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.96s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.6s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.96s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.6s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-9 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-10 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 179.39132690429688px;
  stroke-dasharray: 179.39132690429688px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.08s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.7000000000000002s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.08s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.7000000000000002s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-10 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-11 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 255.83651733398438px;
  stroke-dasharray: 255.83651733398438px;
  fill: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.2s,
                        fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.8s;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.2s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.8s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-11 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 564 242" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="564" height="242">
  <g stroke-width="2" stroke="none" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M284.896413 1.77679122c.882345.50911399 1.614955 1.2417713 2.124036 2.124173l21.099094 36.57152808-23.135682 15.8357502c4.105694 3.2404436 6.948421 5.8686448 8.528184 7.8846038 1.579762 2.0159589 3.442094 5.5716267 5.586996 10.6670034l18.980455-17.1235485 38.506082 66.7434478c1.599912 2.773164.648949 6.318327-2.124036 7.918342-.880865.50826-1.879934.775822-2.896898.775822h-1.922491c-20.321792-10.300399-43.304909-16.104436-67.642638-16.104436-24.337728 0-47.320846 5.804037-67.642638 16.104436h-1.92249c-3.201432 0-5.796706-2.595441-5.796706-5.79708 0-1.01703.267545-2.016163.775772-2.897084L276.978581 3.90096422c1.599913-2.77316415 5.144847-3.7241888 7.917832-2.124173zm-22.79159 66.41506168c-11.912588 9.3077337-11.944524 23.5356033-27.180843 31.0058222 21.073897 5.2094339 33.551253 4.4950599 46.817544-5.8703705 13.266291-10.3654307 12.78672-21.586947 8.366252-27.2452528-4.420468-5.6583057-16.090365-7.1979325-28.002953 2.1098011z" stroke="#00CCAE" fill="#00CCAE" class="svg-elem-1"></path>
    <path d="M20.7357156 241c-3.6819127 0-7.2356044-.568639-10.66118144-1.705935C6.64895709 238.15677 3.95747261 236.68295 2 234.872561l2.58664731-5.431139c1.86425963 1.671128 4.25280646 3.028899 7.16571213 4.073354 2.91290566 1.044455 5.90732776 1.566675 8.98335616 1.566675 4.0547647 0 7.0841412-.684688 9.0882203-2.054085 2.0040791-1.369396 3.0061036-3.191363 3.0061036-5.465954 0-1.671128-.547618-3.028899-1.6428706-4.073354-1.0952525-1.044455-2.4468205-1.845192-4.0547444-2.402235-1.6079239-.557043-3.8799563-1.183706-6.8161652-1.88001-3.6819128-.881984-6.653032-1.763955-8.91344679-2.645939-2.26041481-.881985-4.19455516-2.239756-5.8024791-4.073355-1.60792393-1.833599-2.41187384-4.305438-2.41187384-7.415594 0-2.599532.68743543-4.943718 2.06232691-7.032629 1.37489148-2.08891 3.46050066-3.760013 6.25689011-5.013359 2.79638941-1.253346 6.26852091-1.880009 10.41649861-1.880009 2.8896024 0 5.7325557.371356 8.5289452 1.114079 2.7963894.742724 5.1965877 1.810373 7.2006668 3.20298l-2.3070098 5.570399c-2.0506855-1.299766-4.2411578-2.286181-6.5714823-2.959275-2.3303245-.673093-4.6140083-1.009634-6.8511199-1.009634-3.9615517 0-6.9326709.719502-8.9134468 2.158529-1.98077586 1.439027-2.97114893 3.295808-2.97114893 5.570399 0 1.671129.5592695 3.0289 1.67782528 4.073355 1.11855575 1.044455 2.50507805 1.856797 4.15960855 2.437049 1.6545304.580253 3.9032598 1.195312 6.7462558 1.845195 3.6819127.881984 6.6413805 1.763956 8.8784921 2.64594 2.2371115.88198 4.1596004 2.22815 5.7675244 4.038539 1.6079239 1.810389 2.4118738 4.247414 2.4118738 7.311149 0 2.553112-.6990869 4.885694-2.0972816 6.997814-1.3981947 2.11212-3.5187582 3.783223-6.3617542 5.013359C28.3791277 240.384941 24.8836933 241 20.7357156 241z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-2"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M102.289855 191.724638L80.8535704 240.42029h-6.9126781l-21.5061097-48.695652h7.5411034l17.5959079 40 17.735558-40z" class="svg-elem-3"></path>
    <path d="M152.031506 215.793944h6.654064v19.008987c-2.402868 1.99607-5.198472 3.527914-8.386893 4.595579C147.110255 240.46617 143.783256 241 140.31758 241c-4.898155 0-9.311049-1.079254-13.238815-3.237795-3.927766-2.15854-7.012171-5.12939-9.253308-8.912638-2.241137-3.783249-3.361689-8.04224-3.361689-12.777103 0-4.734863 1.120552-9.00546 3.361689-12.811918 2.241137-3.806459 5.337094-6.777309 9.287965-8.912639 3.95087-2.13533 8.398421-3.202979 13.342785-3.202979 3.881557 0 7.404941.638268 10.570258 1.914824 3.165317 1.276556 5.856952 3.144942 8.074984 5.605214l-4.297416 4.31706c-3.881557-3.760038-8.571701-5.640029-14.070574-5.640029-3.69672 0-7.012167.800736-9.946439 2.402234-2.934273 1.601498-5.233136 3.829635-6.896661 6.684479-1.663524 2.854844-2.495274 6.069396-2.495274 9.643754 0 3.527937.83175 6.719279 2.495274 9.574123 1.663525 2.854844 3.962388 5.094586 6.896661 6.719294 2.934272 1.624708 6.226614 2.43705 9.877126 2.43705 4.343647 0 8.132729-1.044439 11.36736-3.13335v-15.875637z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-4"></path>
    <path d="M233.231687 191.724638l22.101646 48.695652h-7.297713l-5.351657-12.173913h-25.854756l-5.351657 12.173913h-7.158709l22.032144-48.695652h6.880702zm-3.475102 7.095652l-10.494807 23.860869h20.989614l-10.494807-23.860869z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-5"></path>
    <path d="M292.229824 191.724638c6.285416 0 11.230485 1.507231 14.835356 4.521739 3.60487 3.014508 5.407279 7.165191 5.407279 12.452174 0 3.75654-.924312 6.956508-2.772964 9.6-1.848652 2.643491-4.482941 4.56811-7.902946 5.773913l11.507799 16.347826h-7.556326l-10.467938-14.956522c-1.294056.092754-2.310799.139131-3.05026.139131h-11.993067v14.817391h-6.932409v-48.695652h18.925476zm-.207972 6.052174h-11.785095v21.913043h11.785095c4.390548 0 7.741179-.950715 10.051993-2.852174 2.310815-1.901459 3.466205-4.614475 3.466205-8.13913 0-3.524656-1.15539-6.226078-3.466205-8.104348-2.310814-1.87827-5.661445-2.817391-10.051993-2.817391z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-6"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M343.217992 197.776812h-16.580311v-6.052174h40v6.052174H350.05737v42.643478h-6.839378z" class="svg-elem-7"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M384.608696 191.724638h6.956521v48.695652h-6.956521z" class="svg-elem-8"></path>
    <path d="M431.170498 241c-3.681913 0-7.235604-.568639-10.661181-1.705935-3.425577-1.137295-6.117062-2.611115-8.074534-4.421504l2.586647-5.431139c1.86426 1.671128 4.252806 3.028899 7.165712 4.073354 2.912906 1.044455 5.907328 1.566675 8.983356 1.566675 4.054765 0 7.084141-.684688 9.088221-2.054085 2.004079-1.369396 3.006103-3.191363 3.006103-5.465954 0-1.671128-.547618-3.028899-1.64287-4.073354-1.095253-1.044455-2.446821-1.845192-4.054745-2.402235-1.607924-.557043-3.879956-1.183706-6.816165-1.88001-3.681913-.881984-6.653032-1.763955-8.913447-2.645939-2.260415-.881985-4.194555-2.239756-5.802479-4.073355-1.607924-1.833599-2.411874-4.305438-2.411874-7.415594 0-2.599532.687436-4.943718 2.062327-7.032629 1.374892-2.08891 3.460501-3.760013 6.25689-5.013359 2.79639-1.253346 6.268521-1.880009 10.416499-1.880009 2.889602 0 5.732556.371356 8.528945 1.114079 2.796389.742724 5.196588 1.810373 7.200667 3.20298l-2.30701 5.570399c-2.050686-1.299766-4.241158-2.286181-6.571482-2.959275-2.330325-.673093-4.614009-1.009634-6.85112-1.009634-3.961552 0-6.932671.719502-8.913447 2.158529-1.980776 1.439027-2.971149 3.295808-2.971149 5.570399 0 1.671129.55927 3.0289 1.677825 4.073355 1.118556 1.044455 2.505078 1.856797 4.159609 2.437049 1.65453.580253 3.90326 1.195312 6.746256 1.845195 3.681912.881984 6.64138 1.763956 8.878492 2.64594 2.237111.88198 4.1596 2.22815 5.767524 4.038539 1.607924 1.810389 2.411874 4.247414 2.411874 7.311149 0 2.553112-.699087 4.885694-2.097282 6.997814-1.398194 2.11212-3.518758 3.783223-6.361754 5.013359C438.81391 240.384941 435.318476 241 431.170498 241z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-9"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M479.449876 197.776812h-16.580311v-6.052174h40v6.052174h-16.580311v42.643478h-6.839378z" class="svg-elem-10"></path>
    <path d="M539.898353 191.724638L562 240.42029h-7.297714l-5.351656-12.173913h-25.854757l-5.351656 12.173913h-7.15871l22.032145-48.695652h6.880701zm-3.475101 7.095652l-10.494808 23.860869h20.989615l-10.494807-23.860869z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-11"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I would like to "merge" this two and create a single animated SVG files like the one on the wikipedia page here:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/SVG_animation_using_CSS.svg

Any suggestions? I am very new to SVG and graphic styles

Comment: View the source of the page to figure out how this is done in wikipedia. Did you try that? If yes, what specifically didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [SVG Artista - How To](https://svgartista.net/how-to/) page is a very brief explanation ("3. Copy the code") on how to get the transition to work.

Basically you need to add the class name "active" to the SVG element. So, something like this **after** the content of your HTML page has been loaded:

```
document.querySelector('svg').classList.add('active');
```

You can see it running in the Snippet, but here I needed to add the above code to a `setTimeout` and delay it 100 ms (this shouldn't be necessary -- I think that my browser a bit off).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  //document.querySelector('svg').classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('svg').classList.add('active')}, 100);
});
```

```css
svg .svg-elem-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 672.0494384765625px;
  stroke-dasharray: 672.0494384765625px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.8s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(0, 204, 174);
}

svg .svg-elem-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 248.2165985107422px;
  stroke-dasharray: 248.2165985107422px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.12s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.9s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-3 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 217.32936096191406px;
  stroke-dasharray: 217.32936096191406px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.24s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-3 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-4 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 258.3150939941406px;
  stroke-dasharray: 258.3150939941406px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.36s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.1s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-4 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-5 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 255.83644104003906px;
  stroke-dasharray: 255.83644104003906px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.48s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.2000000000000002s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-5 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-6 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 287.29034423828125px;
  stroke-dasharray: 287.29034423828125px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.6s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.3s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-6 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-7 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 179.39129638671875px;
  stroke-dasharray: 179.39129638671875px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.72s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.4000000000000001s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-7 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-8 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 113.3043212890625px;
  stroke-dasharray: 113.3043212890625px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.84s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.5s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-8 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-9 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 248.216552734375px;
  stroke-dasharray: 248.216552734375px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0.96s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.6s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-9 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-10 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 179.39132690429688px;
  stroke-dasharray: 179.39132690429688px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.08s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.7000000000000002s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-10 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}

svg .svg-elem-11 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 255.83651733398438px;
  stroke-dasharray: 255.83651733398438px;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.2s,
                fill 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 1.8s;
}

svg.active .svg-elem-11 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: rgb(29, 27, 29);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 564 242" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="564" height="242">
  <g stroke-width="2" stroke="none" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M284.896413 1.77679122c.882345.50911399 1.614955 1.2417713 2.124036 2.124173l21.099094 36.57152808-23.135682 15.8357502c4.105694 3.2404436 6.948421 5.8686448 8.528184 7.8846038 1.579762 2.0159589 3.442094 5.5716267 5.586996 10.6670034l18.980455-17.1235485 38.506082 66.7434478c1.599912 2.773164.648949 6.318327-2.124036 7.918342-.880865.50826-1.879934.775822-2.896898.775822h-1.922491c-20.321792-10.300399-43.304909-16.104436-67.642638-16.104436-24.337728 0-47.320846 5.804037-67.642638 16.104436h-1.92249c-3.201432 0-5.796706-2.595441-5.796706-5.79708 0-1.01703.267545-2.016163.775772-2.897084L276.978581 3.90096422c1.599913-2.77316415 5.144847-3.7241888 7.917832-2.124173zm-22.79159 66.41506168c-11.912588 9.3077337-11.944524 23.5356033-27.180843 31.0058222 21.073897 5.2094339 33.551253 4.4950599 46.817544-5.8703705 13.266291-10.3654307 12.78672-21.586947 8.366252-27.2452528-4.420468-5.6583057-16.090365-7.1979325-28.002953 2.1098011z" stroke="#00CCAE" fill="#00CCAE" class="svg-elem-1"></path>
    <path d="M20.7357156 241c-3.6819127 0-7.2356044-.568639-10.66118144-1.705935C6.64895709 238.15677 3.95747261 236.68295 2 234.872561l2.58664731-5.431139c1.86425963 1.671128 4.25280646 3.028899 7.16571213 4.073354 2.91290566 1.044455 5.90732776 1.566675 8.98335616 1.566675 4.0547647 0 7.0841412-.684688 9.0882203-2.054085 2.0040791-1.369396 3.0061036-3.191363 3.0061036-5.465954 0-1.671128-.547618-3.028899-1.6428706-4.073354-1.0952525-1.044455-2.4468205-1.845192-4.0547444-2.402235-1.6079239-.557043-3.8799563-1.183706-6.8161652-1.88001-3.6819128-.881984-6.653032-1.763955-8.91344679-2.645939-2.26041481-.881985-4.19455516-2.239756-5.8024791-4.073355-1.60792393-1.833599-2.41187384-4.305438-2.41187384-7.415594 0-2.599532.68743543-4.943718 2.06232691-7.032629 1.37489148-2.08891 3.46050066-3.760013 6.25689011-5.013359 2.79638941-1.253346 6.26852091-1.880009 10.41649861-1.880009 2.8896024 0 5.7325557.371356 8.5289452 1.114079 2.7963894.742724 5.1965877 1.810373 7.2006668 3.20298l-2.3070098 5.570399c-2.0506855-1.299766-4.2411578-2.286181-6.5714823-2.959275-2.3303245-.673093-4.6140083-1.009634-6.8511199-1.009634-3.9615517 0-6.9326709.719502-8.9134468 2.158529-1.98077586 1.439027-2.97114893 3.295808-2.97114893 5.570399 0 1.671129.5592695 3.0289 1.67782528 4.073355 1.11855575 1.044455 2.50507805 1.856797 4.15960855 2.437049 1.6545304.580253 3.9032598 1.195312 6.7462558 1.845195 3.6819127.881984 6.6413805 1.763956 8.8784921 2.64594 2.2371115.88198 4.1596004 2.22815 5.7675244 4.038539 1.6079239 1.810389 2.4118738 4.247414 2.4118738 7.311149 0 2.553112-.6990869 4.885694-2.0972816 6.997814-1.3981947 2.11212-3.5187582 3.783223-6.3617542 5.013359C28.3791277 240.384941 24.8836933 241 20.7357156 241z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-2"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M102.289855 191.724638L80.8535704 240.42029h-6.9126781l-21.5061097-48.695652h7.5411034l17.5959079 40 17.735558-40z" class="svg-elem-3"></path>
    <path d="M152.031506 215.793944h6.654064v19.008987c-2.402868 1.99607-5.198472 3.527914-8.386893 4.595579C147.110255 240.46617 143.783256 241 140.31758 241c-4.898155 0-9.311049-1.079254-13.238815-3.237795-3.927766-2.15854-7.012171-5.12939-9.253308-8.912638-2.241137-3.783249-3.361689-8.04224-3.361689-12.777103 0-4.734863 1.120552-9.00546 3.361689-12.811918 2.241137-3.806459 5.337094-6.777309 9.287965-8.912639 3.95087-2.13533 8.398421-3.202979 13.342785-3.202979 3.881557 0 7.404941.638268 10.570258 1.914824 3.165317 1.276556 5.856952 3.144942 8.074984 5.605214l-4.297416 4.31706c-3.881557-3.760038-8.571701-5.640029-14.070574-5.640029-3.69672 0-7.012167.800736-9.946439 2.402234-2.934273 1.601498-5.233136 3.829635-6.896661 6.684479-1.663524 2.854844-2.495274 6.069396-2.495274 9.643754 0 3.527937.83175 6.719279 2.495274 9.574123 1.663525 2.854844 3.962388 5.094586 6.896661 6.719294 2.934272 1.624708 6.226614 2.43705 9.877126 2.43705 4.343647 0 8.132729-1.044439 11.36736-3.13335v-15.875637z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-4"></path>
    <path d="M233.231687 191.724638l22.101646 48.695652h-7.297713l-5.351657-12.173913h-25.854756l-5.351657 12.173913h-7.158709l22.032144-48.695652h6.880702zm-3.475102 7.095652l-10.494807 23.860869h20.989614l-10.494807-23.860869z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-5"></path>
    <path d="M292.229824 191.724638c6.285416 0 11.230485 1.507231 14.835356 4.521739 3.60487 3.014508 5.407279 7.165191 5.407279 12.452174 0 3.75654-.924312 6.956508-2.772964 9.6-1.848652 2.643491-4.482941 4.56811-7.902946 5.773913l11.507799 16.347826h-7.556326l-10.467938-14.956522c-1.294056.092754-2.310799.139131-3.05026.139131h-11.993067v14.817391h-6.932409v-48.695652h18.925476zm-.207972 6.052174h-11.785095v21.913043h11.785095c4.390548 0 7.741179-.950715 10.051993-2.852174 2.310815-1.901459 3.466205-4.614475 3.466205-8.13913 0-3.524656-1.15539-6.226078-3.466205-8.104348-2.310814-1.87827-5.661445-2.817391-10.051993-2.817391z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-6"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M343.217992 197.776812h-16.580311v-6.052174h40v6.052174H350.05737v42.643478h-6.839378z" class="svg-elem-7"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M384.608696 191.724638h6.956521v48.695652h-6.956521z" class="svg-elem-8"></path>
    <path d="M431.170498 241c-3.681913 0-7.235604-.568639-10.661181-1.705935-3.425577-1.137295-6.117062-2.611115-8.074534-4.421504l2.586647-5.431139c1.86426 1.671128 4.252806 3.028899 7.165712 4.073354 2.912906 1.044455 5.907328 1.566675 8.983356 1.566675 4.054765 0 7.084141-.684688 9.088221-2.054085 2.004079-1.369396 3.006103-3.191363 3.006103-5.465954 0-1.671128-.547618-3.028899-1.64287-4.073354-1.095253-1.044455-2.446821-1.845192-4.054745-2.402235-1.607924-.557043-3.879956-1.183706-6.816165-1.88001-3.681913-.881984-6.653032-1.763955-8.913447-2.645939-2.260415-.881985-4.194555-2.239756-5.802479-4.073355-1.607924-1.833599-2.411874-4.305438-2.411874-7.415594 0-2.599532.687436-4.943718 2.062327-7.032629 1.374892-2.08891 3.460501-3.760013 6.25689-5.013359 2.79639-1.253346 6.268521-1.880009 10.416499-1.880009 2.889602 0 5.732556.371356 8.528945 1.114079 2.796389.742724 5.196588 1.810373 7.200667 3.20298l-2.30701 5.570399c-2.050686-1.299766-4.241158-2.286181-6.571482-2.959275-2.330325-.673093-4.614009-1.009634-6.85112-1.009634-3.961552 0-6.932671.719502-8.913447 2.158529-1.980776 1.439027-2.971149 3.295808-2.971149 5.570399 0 1.671129.55927 3.0289 1.677825 4.073355 1.118556 1.044455 2.505078 1.856797 4.159609 2.437049 1.65453.580253 3.90326 1.195312 6.746256 1.845195 3.681912.881984 6.64138 1.763956 8.878492 2.64594 2.237111.88198 4.1596 2.22815 5.767524 4.038539 1.607924 1.810389 2.411874 4.247414 2.411874 7.311149 0 2.553112-.699087 4.885694-2.097282 6.997814-1.398194 2.11212-3.518758 3.783223-6.361754 5.013359C438.81391 240.384941 435.318476 241 431.170498 241z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-9"></path>
    <path stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" d="M479.449876 197.776812h-16.580311v-6.052174h40v6.052174h-16.580311v42.643478h-6.839378z" class="svg-elem-10"></path>
    <path d="M539.898353 191.724638L562 240.42029h-7.297714l-5.351656-12.173913h-25.854757l-5.351656 12.173913h-7.15871l22.032145-48.695652h6.880701zm-3.475101 7.095652l-10.494808 23.860869h20.989615l-10.494807-23.860869z" stroke="#1D1B1D" fill="#1D1B1D" class="svg-elem-11"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```